# Somar valores de dois inputs e mostrar em terceiro

Tags: javascript, jquery, onblur

Sou iniciante no jQuery e não estou conseguindo somar os valores de dois inputs diferentes e mostrar em um terceiro input o resultado sem dar refresh na tela.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Estes são os campos do formulário:

```
<div class="form-group" id="formvalor"> <!-- Campo para somar -->
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Valor <small>(R$) </small><span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" id="valor_total">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 decimal som" name="valor" id="valor" value="<?php echo $vvalor; ?>" readonly><br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group"> <!-- Campo para somar -->
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Entrada <small>(R$) </small><span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" id="entrada">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 decimal som" name="entrada" value="<?php echo $vvalor; ?>"><br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group"> <!-- Campo para mostrar resultado -->
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Saldo <small>(R$) </small><span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" id="saldo_total">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 decimal" name="saldo" value="<?php echo $vsaldo; ?>" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
```

Estou tentando usar este script:

```
    $("#valor_total, #entrada").on('blur', function(){
    var valortotal = $('#valor_total').val(); 
    var entrada    = $('#entrada').val();

    var resultado   = parseInt(valortotal) + parseInt(entrada);
    $('#saldo_total').val(resultado);
});
```

Quando todos os campos então preenchidos, o resultado da soma não aparece. A `div=saldo_total` fica em branco.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Onde você esta chamando o script? É no clique de algum botão? No evento on-change? No load da página? https://api.jquery.com/category/events/ Se quer algo dinâmico, tente o "change"

Comment: É na troca de input. Com onblur. Mas acredito que o change também resolveria

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Somar inputs com jquery e tempo real](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211767/somar-inputs-com-jquery-e-tempo-real)

Comment: Olá @Mateus Veloso. Tentei seguir os comentários deste tópico, mas não conseguir resolver meu problema com ele, por isso abri este

Comment: Verifique abaixo minha resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exemplo funcional, soma + soma = result.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('input').on('keyup',function(){
    if(jQuery(this).attr('name') === 'result'){
    return false;
    }
  
    var soma1 = (jQuery('#soma1').val() == '' ? 0 : jQuery('#soma1').val());
    var soma2 = (jQuery('#soma2').val() == '' ? 0 : jQuery('#soma2').val());
    var result = (parseInt(soma1) + parseInt(soma2));
    jQuery('#result').val(result);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="soma1" id="soma1" value="" type="text">
<input name="soma2" id="soma2" value="" type="text">
<input name="result" id="result" value="" type="text">
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Mateus Veloso.
Mas no meu código, o campo soma1 ja estaria preenchido automaticamente, e eu preencheria somente o soma2 para mostrar o resultado no result
Mas quando dou alert(soma1) o alert retorna a mensagem undefined :/

Comment: Como você está pegando o soma1 ? mostre seu alert.

Comment: var valor = $('#valor').val();
alert (valor);

Comment: Acredito que seja o value do input, ele é preenchido automaticamente com PHP. Mas o estranho é que quando vou em inspecionar elemento no navegador, o value do input fica com preenchido com o valor que realmente esta nele

Comment: No caso, eu troquei soma1 por #valor

Comment: sim, o problema está no momento que você pega esse value, pode não ter 'carregado' ainda entende? tente colocar em um onload ou utilizar o jQuery como fiz acima, colocando o alert dentro do ready() dessa forma você garante que o elemento já foi escrito em seu dom.

Comment: Reduzindo, coloque seu alert dentro dessa função: `jQuery(document).ready(function(){  alert.....  })`

Comment: Deste modo ele nao trouxe o alert... vou colocar o código no gist para analisar melhor, se possivel

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a5e73dfd84fabfba1f011b3133932ed3

Comment: Coloque o alert abaixo desse trecho de código : jQuery('#saldo').val(result);

Comment: Ficaria assim jQuery('#saldo').val(result); alert....

Comment: Deste jeito ele retorna o alert como undefined novamente

Comment: Quer mover a discussão para o chat? Ja esta muito extensa...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60385/discussion-between-mateus-veloso-and-gabriel).

Answer (score 0):

Faltou você colocar os ids nos campos "input" que é o local que você quer recuperar/inputar o valor...

> Exemplo:

```
<div class="form-group" id="formvalor"> <!-- Campo para somar -->
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Valor <small>(R$) </small><span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" >
        <input type="text" id="valor_total" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 decimal som" name="valor" id="valor" value="<?php echo $vvalor; ?>" readonly><br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group"> <!-- Campo para somar -->
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Entrada <small>(R$) </small><span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" id="entrada" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 decimal som" name="entrada" value="<?php echo $vvalor; ?>"><br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group"> <!-- Campo para mostrar resultado -->
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Saldo <small>(R$) </small><span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" >
        <input type="text" id="saldo_total" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 decimal" name="saldo" value="<?php echo $vsaldo; ?>" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Posso estar enganado mas a julgar pelos inputs de `name="valor"` e   `name="saldo"` que são somente para leitura **(readonly)** e já tem seus values, o que você dá a entender é que se digite um valor no input  `name="entrada"` e no evento onblur te retorne o resultado da soma dos inputs valor entrada e saldo.

Fiz com Javascript, portanto não é necessário qualquer biblioteca.

```js
 function calcular() {
     var num1 = Number(document.getElementById("valor").value);
     var num2 = Number(document.getElementById("entrada").value);
     var num3 = Number(document.getElementById("saldo").value);
     document.getElementById("saldo").value = parseFloat(num1 + num2 + num3).toFixed(2);
 
 }
```

```html
 <div class="form-group" id="formvalor"> <!-- Campo para somar -->
     <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Valor <small>(R$) </small><span class="required">*</span></label>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" id="valor_total">
         <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 decimal som" name="valor" id="valor" value="5" readonly><br>
     </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="form-group"> <!-- Campo para somar -->
     <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Entrada <small>(R$) </small><span class="required">*</span></label>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" id="valor_entrada">
         <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 decimal som" name="entrada" id="entrada" onblur="calcular();"><br>
     </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="form-group"> <!-- Campo para mostrar resultado -->
     <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Saldo <small>(R$) </small><span class="required">*</span></label>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" id="saldo_total">
         <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 decimal" name="saldo"  id="saldo" value="10" readonly>
     </div>
 </div>
```

> OBS: foram colocados ids nos inputs que faltavam

Comment: Olá @Leo Caracciolo. Obrigado pela resposta. Mas eu queria realizar a operação com jQuery, para assim que os  campos forem preenchidos, realizar o cálculo

Comment: @Gabriel pois é, nas suas tags tem javascript, por isso optei pelo mais simples que não precisa de biblioteca de terceiros

Comment: @Gabriel sua pergunta não condiz com seu HTML, vc tem dois inputs somente para leitura (readonly) que já vem preenchidos, sobrando apenas um para digitar algum valor

Comment: Sim. O primeiro readonly ja vem com valor preenchido. O segundo voce digita o valor e faz o calculo com o primeiro, e o terceiro campo, que é o segundo readonly, é onde mostra o resultado deste calculo... O @Mateus Veloso ja me ajudou com isso a acabei descobrindo que não conseguia somar porque os valores passados pelo PHP estavam interferindo no primeiro input (Os valores automaticos dele vem do PHP). Criei um outro tópico para tentar resolver isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212544/passar-valores-de-inputs-para-php